# Automatically Open Sheet, Change Cell, Recalc

Tags: excel, batch-file, vbscript

I have a couple of sheets i'd like to open in the morning (use a batch file that opens the excel sheets and keeps the previous position and size of the window).  For example here is the code to open one of those sheets (I will apply it to others at a later time).

Here is my code for the VBS script:

```
'FILENAME:  OpenSheets.vbs
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\test.xlsm", 4, False
```

Here is my code for the CMD:

```
@echo off
cscript OpenSheets.vbs
cd C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\test
run
```

Within that workbook on sheet1, in cell A1, I have the previous day's date.  I'd like to update that to the current date and then have excel Recalc all (Ctr Alt F9).  Any help would be appreciated.

*Would doing this in perl be easier??*

Comment: What is `cmd` command `run`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in ThisWorkbook:
Open VBA editor with ALT + F11.
Doubleclick Thisworkbook in the project window to the left.
Copy paste and save as xlsm workbook (macroactivated workbook)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = Int(Now())
End Sub
```

Now each time the workbook is opened it will change the date in A1 to todays date